# Display multiple values in a single field in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm new in Symfony2 and Twig.I want to display multiple values in a single field.In my form, I have a field that has 'multiple enabled'.

```
 ->add('name','choice', array(
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'label' => 'Job Done',
        'choices' => array('Wax' => 'Wax', 'Carwash' => 'Carwash','Interior Detailing' =>     'Interior Detailing', 'Exterior Detailing' =>'Exterior Detailing',
        'Full Detailing' => 'Full Detailing', 'Engine Wash' => 'Engine Wash', 'Engine Detailing' => 'Engine Detailing',
        )))
```

With this setup, I can successfully save it in a MYSQL database.But in Twig,(index.html.twig), an error will pop up " Notice: Array to string conversion".

```
{% for entity in entities %}
 <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
 {% endfor %}
```

But if I change to

```
{% for entity in entities %}
<td>{{ entity.name[0] }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Only one value will be displayed.I want to display all values for that field.

In my index.html.twig, all id's has multiple values stored in it.Since I select multiple values.But it only displays one value per id's.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice Twig filter to display array as string (as PHP function `implode` does) :

```
{% for entity in entities %}
    <td>{{ entity.name|join(', ') }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the doc : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/join.html

Comment: This is what I'm looking for.Nice @AlterPHP .

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the error message that you get, a choice field with `multiple` option enabled will return an array. So, to display it in Twig, you need to treat it like any other array. The following code should work:

```
{% for entity in entities %}
    {% for name in entity.name %}
        <td>{{ name }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of approach to print multiple values field on twig file.

```
      {% for genre in node.field_genre %}{{ genre.entity.name.value|join(' ') }}{% endfor %}
```